# Elasticsearch-js client only processes only one match

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I am new to Elasticsearch and want to match multiple queries from the same field. An OR operation in SQL terms. I am using elasticsearch-js client for the communication. Below is my query and log trace which shows the difference.

Query:

```
{body:{ 
  query: {
    bool:{
      should:[
        {
          match:{
          Title:{
            query:["Example 1",],
            operator:  "and"
          }
        },
          match:{
            Title:{
              query:["Example 2",],
              operator:  "and"
            }
        },
          match:{
            Title:{
              query:"Example 3",
              operator: "and"
            }
          }
      }
      ]
    }
  }
}
}
```

But when I see the log trace, it is executing the below query:

```
{
 query": {
      "bool": {
        "should": [
          {
            "match": {
              "Title": {
                "query": "Sports Coaching",
                "operator": "and"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

Also when I use filter, it always returns me zero results.
Will appreciate the help.

Comment: All your `match` queries should be surrounded by `{` and `}` not only the first one